# Selenium unblock the suspend of a webpage

Tags: javascript, java, python, selenium, html

I am having a trouble with how to solve the suspension of a webpage as in below image
[image].

I am trying to get into the ticket selling webpage every 0.1 seconds that it will count down for 10 seconds if it is busy

[link http://busy.hkticketing.com/](http://busy.hkticketing.com/).

And I am doing something like this in selenium

```
while True:
browser.execute_script('location.replace("http://www.hkticketing.com/");
time.sleep(0.1)
```

and the server had brought me into a suspension of the webpage with the following message:

> Your current browsing or purchase process has been temporarily
>   suspended because our system detects abnormal behavior, for example,
>   refreshing this website too frequently, which may interfere with the
>   proper operation of this website. You will immediately regain access
>   after completing the CAPTCHA below.

may I know that is there any way to get out of the suspension or is there any way to avoid getting into the suspension of that webpage?

Great thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to automate www.hkticketing.com for you practice and the website does not allows so many attempts of ticket selling from the same ip address. This will there for a lot of websites to avoid unnecessary traffic and hacking. If this is the case, I think you should switch to some other websites which are made for for automation practice only:
https://www.techbeamers.com/websites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online/

If this is not the case and you are doing it officially, then you might get this feature disabled on the test environment and can proceed with the automation execution on the test environment.